# How to execute a piece of code during installation of extension in VSCode extension making?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to install some dependencies when im installing my custom extension for VSCode. It might also be preferable to run a piece of code when i first install this extension in VSCode. Where do i write that code??

Comment: Extensions install their dependencies in first run, not during extension installation.

Comment: and how do i execute code in first run? sorry but im new to extension development... any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: use a setting to mark if you have run before, or use a file in the extension to write the version number that has done its first run

Comment: Most of the extensions are open sourced, so if you analyze a typical one you will see how. I wrote a summary here, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-acquire-dependencies-for-visual-studio-code-extensions-9ca828cb168d